# readable.destroy() not emitting both 'close' and 'error' events Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, streaming, dom-events

I wrote some code that happens to work, but I thought that `readable.destroy()` (eg, `src.destroy()`, in my example) is supposed to emit `close` and `error` events...

Here's a somewhat minimal example to illustrate my confusion:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const src = fs.createReadStream('streaming-example.js');
const dst = fs.createWriteStream('streaming-example.txt');
src.pipe(dst);
src.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = src.read())) {
    /**
    * This should cause 'error' and 'close' events to emit
    * @see https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error
    */
    src.destroy();
  }
});
src.on('close', () => console.log(`'close' event emitted`));
src.on('end', () => console.log(`'end' event emitted`));
src.on('error', (err) => console.log(`'error' event emitted`));
```

And here's a sample run of that program:

```sh
$ node streaming-example.js 
'close' event emitted
$
```

(and, it happens to also finish writing to a new file named `streaming-example.txt`)

If it's not clear, I expected the `close` and `error` events to be emitted and in turn to trigger the corresponding callbacks. However, only the `close` event seems to have been emitted.

What happened to the `error` event emission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that taking a peak into the node.js codebase elucidates this confusion.

Taking a look at [node/lib/_stream_readable.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js), we see that the destroy function is defined in [node/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js). Here, we are directly told (through plain javascript) that the `error` event is only ever emitted when exactly one truthy value is passed into the destroy function (which, semantically, would be an error generated in the same client code that `destroy` is invoked in).

For example, if we simply modify the above example code by changing

```
readable.destroy();
```

to be

```
readable.destroy(true); // or, more semantically correct, some Error value
```

we get the following output:

```sh
$ node streaming-example.js 
'error' event emitted with err: true
$
```

However, now we lost the `close` event. So... what just happened?

Taking a look again at [node/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js), we notice the following special-case logic:

```
const readableDestroyed = this._readableState &&
  this._readableState.destroyed;
const writableDestroyed = this._writableState &&
  this._writableState.destroyed;

if (readableDestroyed || writableDestroyed) {
  if (cb) {
    cb(err);
  } else if (err &&
              (!this._writableState || !this._writableState.errorEmitted)) {
    process.nextTick(emitErrorNT, this, err);
  }
  return this;
}

// We set destroyed to true before firing error callbacks in order
// to make it re-entrance safe in case destroy() is called within callbacks

if (this._readableState) {
  this._readableState.destroyed = true;
}

// If this is a duplex stream mark the writable part as destroyed as well
if (this._writableState) {
  this._writableState.destroyed = true;
}
```

The fact that `error` is correctly emitted, but it appears `close` is not emitted hints to us that we're dealing with a duplex stream. We could just look up what that is, but let's stick with what the computer tells us, to keep it simple. Replacing the original while-loop with this while-loop

```
while (null !== (chunk = src.read())) {
  console.log('before-destroy, src:', JSON.stringify(src));
  src.destroy(true);  // should cause 'close' and 'error' events to emit
  console.log('after-destroy, src:', JSON.stringify(src));       
}
```

we get the following output:

```
$ node streaming-example.js 
before-destroy, src: {"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":65536,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":{"_writableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"finalCalled":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"destroyed":false,"decodeStrings":true,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":633,"writing":true,"corked":0,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writelen":633,"bufferedRequest":null,"lastBufferedRequest":null,"pendingcb":1,"prefinished":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":false,"autoDestroy":false,"bufferedRequestCount":0,"corkedRequestsFree":{"next":null,"entry":null}},"writable":true,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":5,"path":"streaming-example.txt","fd":24,"flags":"w","mode":438,"autoClose":true,"bytesWritten":0,"closed":false},"pipesCount":1,"flowing":false,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":true,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":true,"resumeScheduled":false,"paused":false,"emitClose":false,"autoDestroy":false,"destroyed":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":true,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"_events":{"end":[null,null,null]},"_eventsCount":5,"path":"streaming-example.js","fd":23,"flags":"r","mode":438,"end":null,"autoClose":true,"bytesRead":633,"closed":false}
after-destroy, src: {"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":65536,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":{"_writableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"finalCalled":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"destroyed":false,"decodeStrings":true,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":633,"writing":true,"corked":0,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writelen":633,"bufferedRequest":null,"lastBufferedRequest":null,"pendingcb":1,"prefinished":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":false,"autoDestroy":false,"bufferedRequestCount":0,"corkedRequestsFree":{"next":null,"entry":null}},"writable":true,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":5,"path":"streaming-example.txt","fd":24,"flags":"w","mode":438,"autoClose":true,"bytesWritten":0,"closed":false},"pipesCount":1,"flowing":false,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":true,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":true,"resumeScheduled":false,"paused":false,"emitClose":false,"autoDestroy":false,"destroyed":true,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":true,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"_events":{"end":[null,null,null]},"_eventsCount":5,"path":"streaming-example.js","fd":null,"flags":"r","mode":438,"end":null,"autoClose":true,"bytesRead":633,"closed":false}
'error' event emitted
$
```

which tells us that we're probably dealing with a duplex stream, or at least this explains to us exactly why only the `error` event is emitted (because, specifically just looking at the `after-destroy` output, both `this._readableState` and `this._writeableState` are truthy, and therefore the `destroy` function sets the local variables `readableDestroyed` and `writeableDestroyed` to true, and we notice from the `console.log` that `this._writableState.errorEmitted` is `false`, so `process.nextTick(emitErrorNT, this, err);` is executed right before exiting from the `destroy` function).

The question has now been sufficiently answered.

As an extra, it's good to know what the difference between a `duplex` stream vs some other kind of stream is. For that, a quick reference of [this portion of the node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_types_of_streams) is a start.

---

So, what about an example when both the `close` and `error` events are emitted (ie, when we're not dealing with a `duplex` stream? The following code and execution does that, as shown below:

```
const readable = process.stdin;
const writable = process.stdout;
readable.setEncoding('utf8');
readable.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while ((chunk = readable.read()) !== null) {
    writable.write(`data: ${chunk}`);
  }
  readable.destroy(true);
});
readable.on('close', () => console.log(`'close' event emitted`));
readable.on('error', (err) => console.log(`'error' event emitted with err:`, err));
```

Executing this script, along with some I/O (typing `asdf` followed by hitting the return/enter key), provides the following output:

```sh
$ node streaming-example2.js 
asdf
data: asdf
'error' event emitted with err: true
'close' event emitted
$
```